# Proguard : Prevent to changing class name and methods name

Tags: java, android

How can i prevent pro-guard to change class names and methods name that is extended from special class, i am using following code , but it's does not work and my special class method names changing

```
-keep public class * extends com.test.android.util.FactoryBase
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.test.android.util.FactoryBase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-keep public class * extends com.test.android.util.FactoryBase
{
   *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends com.test.android.util.FactoryBase
{
   *;
}
```

If you want to only keep certain methods, then instead of `*;`, try this:

```
-keep public class * extends com.test.android.util.FactoryBase
{
   public void doSomething(...);
   public int doSomethingElse(...);
}
```

I would recommend you to read more on the things you can do [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html)

Comment: please post the class you're trying to keep / the methods which are changing.

Comment: I used invalid class package , i fixed it and it's working now very well,thanks :)

Comment: I have another question, how can i do this for a package?i want to prevent to changing package name , classes in this package , and methods in classes.thanks

Comment: you can use: -keep public class com.part.of.package.**

Comment: need i insert bracket?

Comment: probably, to explain what exactly you'd like to be kept.

Comment: -keep public class * extends com.pkg.computaion.CalculateSum
{
   public int sum(...);
   public int multiply(...);
}

Comment: The class itself getting removed.Any help appreciated